# how to show progress dialog in oncreate in android app

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, progress

In onCreate() of the activity, I'm force changing the orientation of the activity from portrait to landscape. This is working but there is a small delay of about a sec in the emulator. This activity is actually one of the tabs. So when the user clicks on the tab he would expect an immediate response. So I want to show a progress dialog until the view is completely loaded. How do I  achieve this? I tried to do the below but it doesn't work,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.chart);

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    .
    .
    .
    dialog.dismiss();//after the view is loaded completely   }
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does the delay happen if you are in landscape to start with? If your view takes that long to load, load a simpler view in onCreate, then fire up a background task to load the "real" view and then invoke `setContentView(loadedChartView)` through a handler.

Comment: "This is working but there is a small delay of about a sec in the emulator." - Try your Activity on real devices without your ProgressDialog. My experience of the emulator is that it often has serious lag.

Comment: @Ted: Yes. there is a delay even if i'm in the landscape mode to start with. I think the delay is probably because, in addition to forcing the orientation of the activity to be landscape, i'm also hiding the tab bar.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Now, there's a thought. I wish I could test it on a real device. Still, switching between other tabs is very fast in the emulator. So I should expect switching to the 'chart' tab also must be fast without any delay. The only thing 'chart' tab is doing different is that, the orientation changes and the tab bar is being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think your application is visiable yet .. not at the onCreate().  Check the eventing lifecycle ... onResume or maybe onStart ... where ever your Acitivity is actually visiable is where you should do this.